# Unexpected Output - Storing into 2D array in c

Tags: c

I am reading data from a number of files, each containing a list of words. I am trying to display the number of words in each file, but I am running into issues. For example, when I run my code, I receive the output as shown below.

Almost every amount is correctly displayed with the exception of two files, each containing word counts in the thousands. Every other file only has three digits worth of words, and they seem just fine.

I can only guess what this problem could be (not enough space allocated somewhere?) and I do not know how to solve it. I apologize if this is all poorly worded. My brain is fried and I am struggling. Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried to keep my example code as brief as possible. I've cut out a lot of error checking and other tasks related to the full program. I've also added comments where I can. Thanks.

StopWords.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char stopwords[2000][60];
    int wordcount;
} LangData;

typedef struct
{
    int languageCount;
    LangData languages[];
} AllData;


main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Initialize data structures and open path directory
    int langCount = 0;
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *ep;
    d = opendir(argv[1]);

    //Count the number of language files in the directory
    while(readdir(d))
        langCount++;

    //Account for "." and ".." in directory
    //langCount = langCount - 2 THIS MAKES SENSE RIGHT?
    langCount = langCount + 1; //The program crashes if I don't do this, which doesn't make sense to me.

    //Allocate space in AllData for languageCount
    AllData *data = malloc(sizeof(AllData) + sizeof(LangData)*langCount); //Unsure? Seems to work.

    //Reset the directory in preparation for reading data
    rewinddir(d);

    //Copy all words into respective arrays.
    char word[60];
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while((ep = readdir(d)) != NULL) //Probably could've used for loops to make this cleaner. Oh well.
    {
        if (!strcmp(ep->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(ep->d_name, ".."))
        {
            //Filtering "." and ".."
        }
        else
        {
            FILE *entry;

            //Get string for path (i should make this a function)
            char fullpath[100];
            strcpy(fullpath, path);
            strcat(fullpath, "\\");
            strcat(fullpath, ep->d_name);

            entry = fopen(fullpath, "r");

            //Read all words from file
            while(fgets(word, 60, entry) != NULL)
            {
                j = 0;

                //Store each word one character at a time (better way?) 
                while(word[j] != '\0') //Check for end of word
                {
                    data->languages[i].stopwords[k][j] = word[j];
                    j++; //Move onto next character
                }
                k++; //Move onto next word
                data->languages[i].wordcount++;
            }

            //Display number of words in file
            printf("%d\n", data->languages[i].wordcount);
            i++; Increment index in preparation for next language file.

            fclose(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
256 //czech.txt: Correct
101 //danish.txt: Correct
101 //dutch.txt: Correct
547 //english.txt: Correct
1835363006 //finnish.txt: Should be 1337. Of course it's 1337.
436 //french.txt: Correct
576 //german.txt: Correct
737 //hungarian.txt: Correct
683853 //icelandic.txt: Should be 1000.
399 //italian.txt: Correct
172 //norwegian.txt: Correct
269 //polish.txt: Correct
437 //portugese.txt: Correct
282 //romanian.txt: Correct
472 //spanish.txt: Correct
386 //swedish.txt: Correct
209 //turkish.txt: Correct
```

Comment: Have you verified that a normal text editor can display the file correctly? Maybe it's an encoding issue? Are all words verified to be less than 60 bytes, including a newline character (note that I said "bytes" and not "characters")? This is all assuming that the file was opened correctly (`entry` isn't `NULL`), and the fields were filled properly as a result, instead of leaving them uninitialized with whatever values are in memory at the time you called `malloc()` since the `fgets()` loop will pretty much be skipped (and `ferror(entry)` would return a non-zero value).

Comment: The file can be opened in a standard text editor. All files are in UTF-8. The longest word in finnish.txt is "toimitusjohtaja" not anywhere near 60 bytes, but just in case I upped it to 200, and received the exact same output. I have inserted a line that prints each word as it is read in one at a time until I press enter and the file is being read in properly all the way to the end, but the count is wrong for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

Do the files have more than 2000 words? You have only allocated space for 2000 words so once your program tries to copy over word 2001 it will be doing it outside of the memory allocated for that array, possibly into the space allocated for "wordcount".

Also I want to point out that fgets returns a string to the end of the line or at most n characters (60 in your case), whichever comes first.  This will work find if there is only one word per line in the files you are reading from, otherwise will have to locate spaces within the string and count words from there.

If you are simply trying to get a word count, then there is no need to store all the words in an array in the first place.  Assuming one word per line, the following should work just as well:

```
 char word[60];
 while(fgets(word, 60, entry) != NULL)
        {
            data->languages[i].wordcount++;
        }
```

fgets reference- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/

**Update**
I took another look and you might want to try allocating data as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    char stopwords[2000][60];
    int wordcount;
} LangData;

typedef struct
{
    int languageCount;
    LangData *languages;
} AllData;

AllData *data = malloc(sizeof(AllData));
data->languages = malloc(sizeof(LangData)*langCount);
```

This way memory is being specifically allocated for the languages array.

I agree that langCount = langCount - 2 makes sense. What error are you getting?

Comment: The largest number of words in a file is 1337 and the files do have only one word per line. There is more to my program that I didn't show here that I need to store the words for (I need to look them up later). However, I tried increasing the number of words I can store to 4000, and the amount of characters from 60 to 2000, and the two that were giving me issues before are now being displayed properly, but another one is wrong. Update: I just upped the limits to 10000 each to say I did and now it is all being displayed properly. It seems ridiculous and I don't know why it works.